# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] Issue with .htaccess mode_rewrite

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, action

I created clean url with .htaccess,

```
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]


     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

.php is removed, but wherever I have a form where

```
     action = somepage.php
```

I am forced to change it to

```
      action = somepage
```

these are old websites I am fixing, luckily one has all

```
     action =$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

is there someway to resolve so action takes the posted values no matter if

action = somepage.php or

action somepage or

action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

So Instead of

```
   form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="actionfr.php"
```

I am forced to change it to:

```
     form  method="post" action="actionfr"
```

Same goes for

```
      form method="post" action="<?php echo   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

Many Thanks

P.S I learned how to make clean url .htaccess here on this forum (y) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to replace every occurrence with :

```
 action="<?php echo str_replace('.php','',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>"
```

Had to go to every file